# how to set resource of imageView in xamarin.android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

i`m new in xamarin.android i want to know how can i set resources for my image view widget?
i did put my images in Assets folder but i dont know how to use them please give an example thanks!
here is my attempt without any result:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        ImageView img = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        img.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.); // i cant find my images here
```

Comment: `...put my images in Assets folder...` You are using Resource.Drawable.xxx, so add the image to your Resouce/Drawable folder.

Comment: @SushiHangover i tried but still it doesn't recognize images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project, the image should be placed in the `Drawable` folder like this:

[image]

Then you can access your image by:

```
ImageView img = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.myImage);
img.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.test);
```

Or set it in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yeap it works after putting images in drawable folder and restart visual studio but i dont recommend xamarin for android programming just use android studio!